# Fragment's onCreate and onCreateView are not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm building an application which receive an action.SEND `Intent` and display all files in clip data into a `ListView`. My `ListView` is inside a `ShareFragment` which hosted by my `MainActiviy`. Below is how i implement it.

```
public class ShareFragment extends MFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ShareFragment";
    private List<File> files;
    private FileAdapter fileAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate called");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        files = new ArrayList<>();
        fileAdapter = new FileAdapter(getActivity(), 0, files);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_fragment, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(fileAdapter);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView called");
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setData(List<File> files){
        Log.e(TAG, "setData called");
        this.files = files;
        fileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And here is how i used it in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        shareFragment = (ShareFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("share_fragment");
        if(shareFragment == null) {
            shareFragment = new ShareFragment();
            shareFragment.setTitle("Share");
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fl_root, shareFragment, "share_fragment");
        ft.commit();
        handleIntent(intent);
    }
```

Here is `handleIntent` method:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if ((Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) || Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action)) && type != null) {
        int size = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            File file = new File(intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri().getPath());
            files.add(file);
        }
        shareFragment.setData(files);
    }
}
```

***My problem is***
When my application are started by receive an `action.SEND` `Intent`, it ran into `onCreate` and processed this line `shareFragment = new ShareFragment()`

**But**
`onCreate` and `onCreateView` of `ShareFragment` is never called. **why?**

**Note** I thought the `FragmentManager` kept an instance of `ShareFragment` when my app first ran. So i try to found my fragment to reused it, but it always returned null.

**EDIT**
I got a `NullPointerException` right at `fileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void icetea.com.quickshare.adapter.FileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
            at icetea.com.quickshare.fragments.ShareFragment.setData(ShareFragment.java:49)
            at icetea.com.quickshare.MainActivity.handleIntent(MainActivity.java:63)
            at icetea.com.quickshare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: move handleIntent(intent); into onResume() , you try to set the data in onCreate, but at this time the fragment isn't created

Comment: @fmt.Println.MKO it work, seem the creation of `Fragment` is not in UI thread. You can write down your answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `handleIntent(intent);` into *onResume()*

you try to set the data in onCreate, but at this time the fragment isn't created

you find more about this in the Fragments documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle